# How do I make an interactive table in python, using Spyder?

Tags: matplotlib, spyder, onclicklistener, python-interactive

At the end of a long script, I have some outputs that I would like to be able to visualize a number of ways. The following describes what I want and is inspired by similar functionality in Matlab that doesn't seem to be available in Python/Spyder.

1. create a table from a data frame (columns = headers, rows = entries). This part is obviously not the challenging part.
2. make this table interactive so that it can register when there is a click. I am fine with this being a click anywhere on the row corresponding to a given entry or a click on a particular new column designated for that purpose.
3. when a click is registered for a given entry, 2 plotting functions are called, with the information from that particular entry used as input.

To summarize, the challenge is finding a package that allows for interactive TABLES in Spyder which trigger a plotting function when clicked.

Matplotlib seems to have most of the interactivity functionality I want (https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html), but not starting with a table.

I also have a large number of output files and need to run this Spyder script iteratively, so a solution using ipynb is not a suitable option for me.

These plots are large and there are many of them, so a large, scrollable table is also not ideal, as I would prefer to only make the plots as needed.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create an interactive GUI in Python. Can you add a brief description of how you would do this in MATLAB and what kind of plots you need? I think this is independent of Spyder unless you need it to be integrated in some way - if so, please describe that too. There are some examples of GUIs using matplotlib [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/index.html). Your first task will be deciding which GUI framework to use, because there are several to choose from - a consequence of the open nature of Python compared to MATLAB, unfortunately.